# ScrollViewer capture events that belong overlapping controls

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

If we have a ScrollViewer with scrollable content , and a control that is above , not contained within it, such as a button , we can move the ScrollViewer only touching the button.

[image: Explanatory example]

XAML root content:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="GRID" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SCROLLVIEWER">
            <StackPanel x:Name="STACKPANEL">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="3" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="4" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="5" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="6" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="7" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="8" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="9" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Button x:Name="BUTTON" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="364" Width="278"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I tried to avoid this behavior in different ways, without success, like use Canvas Layout.

**EDIT**

Can't be separated in diferent columns, the content of ScrollViewer can be wider.

[image]

What do you advise me?

Comment: Do you apply an implicit default style for buttons, that may set `HitTestVisible` to false? Try setting it to true explicitly for your x:Name="BUTTON" element and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank's @Martin I tried your advice, but don't work for me, I still can scroll only touching the button.

Comment: can you verify that the behavior is still present when you run your app on an actual phone? maybe it is just a glitch in the emulator, passing the swipe-events to the wrong element (based purely on x/y coordinates and ignoring z-order)

Comment: here is another test: change the order of appearance in the xaml: the button first, then the scrollviewer, and set Canvas.ZIndex="42" on the button (**Yes it works in a grid**)

Comment: Tested whit WP8.0&WP8.1 Emulator & WP8.0&WP8.1 device IN DEBUG.
1 Time in release with device WP8.1.

Comment: Here is a link to the project that I started today to see if I discover how to isolate the event only to the button .
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmf80o1uzg3be30/BadScroll.zip?dl=0

Comment: In another proyects I also try to change ManipulationStartedEventArgs.Hanled = true or GestureEventArgs.Handled = true in various events from button.
In GestureEventArgs.Handled Remarks says something about AddHandler(RoutedEvent,Delegate,Boolean). I think that changing this in ScrollViewer can be the solution, but don't know how.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.input.gestureeventargs.handled%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Have you tried the Canvas.ZIndex thingy? I'm really curious if the order in which the elements are placed in xaml does make a difference.

Comment: Yes, dont work. In Attached file BadScroll in the comments Zindex was used.
Seems I must change the Handler of the ScrollViewer, this is an routed event. But the button and the Scrollview isn't in the same branch of the XAML tree XD.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758286.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Grid.Columns` to separate both controls. Now `ScrollViewer`and Button Lies in Same Column, So whenever you try to access the `ScrollViewer`there is a possibility to access button also. SO try Like this

```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="GRID" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SCROLLVIEWER">
            <StackPanel x:Name="STACKPANEL">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="3" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="4" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="5" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="6" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="7" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="8" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="9" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Button x:Name="BUTTON" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="200" Grid.Column="1"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You can get rid-off the behavior You can access both controls separately.

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh balan, but can't be separated in two columns, I edit the post.